# How to avoid web browser warning when my site use HTTPS protocol, and it's pages include images from sites without HTTPS?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, https

I have java web application which is running on several tomcats behind apache. Application use HTTPS protocol. Some pages from the app include images from sites which use only HTTP protocol. On pages with this images the client's web browser shows message (warning) that despite service is certified correctly some contents are not secure. 
What should I do to avoid this message? Should I use some proxy for this images? Can I do something in java code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obtain a valid SSL certificate and use that in your Apache/Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything nor should you.

The browser is correct in warning the user even though there are no bad intentions here.

Using a proxy could be useful if you're really worried. In that case, the unencrypted connection is between your server and the hosts of the images instead of between the hosts and the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do in java.

You need to register your certificate at some official certification authority, you can do that through the registration authorities.

> A registration authority (RA) is an authority in a network that
>   verifies user requests for a digital certificate and tells the
>   certificate authority (CA) to issue it.

Google it. Of course you'll pay for that.

Also, you can avoid that browser message if manually add your certificate into Trusted Certificate on client machine.